# Google Drive API v2 downloadUrl isn't being properly authenticated

Tags: php, api, google-drive-api

I've got a problem with the downloadUrl property that is returned after I make an authorized request with an access token. If I try to use that downloadUrl in the browser, it will give an HTTP Error 403. I've double checked and my access token is valid and I can make requests for file metadata that way, and that's how I'm able to get the downloadUrl in the first place.
Here is my code right now:

```
<?php
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');
include_once "examples/templates/base.php";

$client = new Google_Client();
$credentials_file = __DIR__.'/credentials.json';
putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS='.$credentials_file);
if ($credentials_file = checkServiceAccountCredentialsFile()) {
    // set the location manually
    $client->setAuthConfig($credentials_file);
} elseif (getenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS')) {
    // use the application default credentials
    $client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
} else {
    echo missingServiceAccountDetailsWarning();
    exit;
}

$client->setApplicationName('test-debug');
$client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly'));
$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

$id = "some-id-here";

$pre = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/";

$tokenArray = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAssertion();
$accessToken = $tokenArray["access_token"];

$content = json_decode(file_get_contents($pre.$id."?access_token=".$accessToken));
$downloadUrl = $content->{'downloadUrl'};
echo $downloadUrl;

?>
```

With this code, I can successfully make a request to Google's API and retrieve the downloadUrl parameter. The only problem is, it isn't valid for some reason. Would anyone know exactly why this is happening? Does it have something to do with how I make the request with an access token? Please chime in if you think you have an answer to this problem.

**P.S.** I'd also like to mention that by using php cURL an error 401 is returned instead of an error 403

Answer (score 0):

So, upon checking [Drive v2 PHP Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/quickstart/php),

> Drive v2 is no longer supported by the PHP client library. See the
>   [Drive v3 PHP Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/php) instead.

To start in Drive v3 you'll need the ff.

> - PHP 5.4 or greater with the command-line interface (CLI) and JSON extension installed.
> - The [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) dependency management tool.
> - Access to the internet and a web browser.
> - A Google account with Google Drive enabled.

Comment: Ahh, yea that makes sense why it isn't working. But the Drive v3 PHP quickstart won't help me in my situation. I'm running a web server with no access to a console. What I'm trying to do is use a service account and get no consent from the user at all. And then using the service account to download a file to the user's PC. I'm able to do this with drive api v3 except that the file downloaded is not the right file name. That's why I wanted to use the downloadUrl from drive v2.
May I add that this url accomplishes exactly what I'm trying to do: https://links-safety.com/download.php?id={FILE-ID}